# php curl to self signed certificate url

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I'm not a php developer! I'm just trying to make php curl work on my localhost, talking to my REST service...

**Note:** I have a self-signed certificate and I suspect php curl goes to [http://localhost:8443/myapp/oauth/token] instead of [https://localhost:8443/myapp/oauth/token]

But I couldn't figure out why?

Here is my code below;

```
public function oauth2() {

    echo 'Starting...<br/>';

    $postargs = array(
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 'some-client',
            'client_secret' => 'some-secret',
            'scope' => 'play,trust',
            'username' => 'tester',
            'password' => '121212'
    );
    $url = 'https://localhost:8443/myapp/oauth/token';

    try {
        $this->load->library('curl');
        $curl_handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PORT, 8443);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        //curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        //curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        //curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);

        $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        if (curl_errno($curl_handle)) {
            echo curl_error($curl_handle).'<br/>';
        } else {
            //echo curl_getinfo($curl_handle);
            curl_close($curl_handle);
            echo '<p>'.$buffer.'</p>';

        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception....<br/>';
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
        die;
    }
    echo 'Continue...<br/>';
    die;
}
```

Above doesn't work... Why do I get "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue" in the beginning? It shouldn't be like that! Here is the response I see.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 401 
Unauthorized Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Cache-Control: no-store 
Pragma: no-cache 
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="***/client",
error="unauthorized",
error_description="An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"
Content-Type: application/json;
charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Fri,
10 Jan 2014 04:44:40 GMT 
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"}
```

However when I run curl from command line like below it works!

```
curl -k -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "grant_type=password&client_id=some-client&client_secret=some-secret&scope=play,trust&username=tester&password=121212" [https://localhost:8443/myapp/oauth/token]

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 10 Jan 2014 04:56:45 GMT

{"access_token":"cee03c37-9168-4dca-8ffe-bd7f469cdcb5","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5238,"scope":"play trust","client_id":"...."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

Changing below line worked!

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=password&client_id=....&client_secret=....&scope=play,trust&username=tester&password=121212");

Instead of an array it needed a string.